# Перевод строки в message aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, циклы, aiogram

Есть запрос из бд в в aiogram бота

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='list') # запрос вопроса из бд
async def get_qwestions_list(message: types.Message):
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('data.db')
    cur = base.cursor()

    qwestion=cur.execute('SELECT * FROM qwestions').fetchall()
    for qwestion_list in qwestion:
        for qwestion_list_1 in qwestion_list:
            await message.answer(qwestion_list_1)
```

Получаю:

```
1
Первый вопрос
2
Второй вопрос
3
Третий вопрос
4
Четвертый вопрос
```

А надо :

```
1 Первый вопрос
2 Второй вопрос
3 Третий вопрос
4 Четвертый вопрос
```

Как реализовать?

Comment: Как выглядит ваша бд?

Comment: Примерно так:
number.  qwes
1.             Первый вопрос
2.             Второй вопрос
3.             Третий вопрос
4              Четвертый вопрос

если вы имели ввиду структуру таблицы

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='list')
async def get_qwestions_list(message: types.Message):
    base = sq.connect('data.db')
    cur = base.cursor()

    qwestion = cur.execute('SELECT qwes FROM qwestions').fetchall()
    result = ""
    for qwestion_list in qwestion:
        for num, qwestion_list_1 in enumerate(qwestion_list):
            result += f"{num}. {qwestion_list_1}\n"
    await message.answer(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Все таки не совсем то(, потестил. В итоге нужно чтобы именно из БД брал номер вопроса и из бд брал сам вопрос

Comment: сделайте принт `qwestion_list` сразу после начала for и отправьте сюда ответ